# Can a Covariance matrix have negative elements?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, random-variables, standard-deviation

I have a $N \times N$ covariance matrix $C$ of a multivariate Normal distribution.  Can any of the elements of the Covariance matrix $C$ be negative for a real-valued distributions ?

Answer (score 4):

Any negative correlation between two elements will end up with a corresponding negative entry in the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example  $$ \begin{pmatrix} a+b  & a-b \\ a-b & a+b \end{pmatrix} $$ can appear as covariance matrix for any positive eigenvalues $2a$, $2b$.